# nifi routeText processor usage issue

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I am facing issue in configuring RouteText Processor correctly. I have to filter out those lines which have say a particular string values at a particular index. Let's say I want all the lines which have 'BT'  or 'PV7' and 'PV30'  values at index 19. My file is csv.

I tried using below configuration but all of my lines are moved to unmatched relation. However, data is containing other lines too.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the Matching Strategy to "Satisfies Expression" since you are not using regular expressions here.

The docs for Satisfies Expression says:

"Match lines based on whether or not the the text satisfies the given Expression Language expression. I.e., the line will match if the property value, evaluated as an Expression, returns true. The expression is able to reference FlowFile Attributes, as well as the variables 'line' (which is the text of the line to evaluate) and 'lineNo' (which is the line number being evaluated. This will be 1 for the first line, 2 for the second and so on)."